# 1D density of states help

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, density-of-states

I am given a 1D band whose energy is $$E(k)=E_0-t\cos(ak)$$ 
Then I have to compute the DOS relative to that band.  Here is my calculation: $$g(E)=\dfrac{1}{L}\dfrac{dN}{dk}\dfrac{dk}{dE}$$ where $\dfrac{dN}{dk}=\dfrac{d}{dk}\left(\dfrac{2kL}{\pi}\right)$ and $\dfrac{dk}{dE}=\dfrac{1}{at\sin(ak)}$. Then calculating k from $E(k)$ and substituting it into $\dfrac{dk}{dE}$ I obtain $$ g(E)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\dfrac{1}{at\sin(\cos^{-1}([E_0-E(k)]/t))} $$
Then I would like to ask: is it correct to preceed like this? Moreover, how can I evaluate if there are some Van Hove singularities?

Comment: The sine of an arccosine is a simple square root, which can be derived via trigonometric identities or by drawing a suitable triangle with the right sides for the specified cosine and reading out the sine.